# Useful XML functions to improve parsing performance without looping? C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, performance

I'm working on a WCF service application which does lot of manipulations on XML files. Before i start looping the nodes, elements, attributes and all the other stuffs i want to know the useful functions that are available on XmlNode, XmlElement, XmlDocument and all other Xml related classes which can be used 'in place of' looping.

For example you can convert List to array using the `CopyTo(string[])`.

Thank you.

NLV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the immediate answer is LINQ. A "scratch-pad" example of using it would be:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace LinqSample1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = @"
        <items>
            <item>
                <name>Item 1</name>
                <price>1.00</price>
                <quantity>3</quantity>
            </item>
            <item>
                <name>Item 2</name>
                <price>1.50</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
        </items>";

            var document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml(xml);

            var items = from XmlNode item in document.SelectNodes("/items/item")
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = item.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText,
                            Price = item.SelectSingleNode("price").InnerText,
                            Quantity = item.SelectSingleNode("quantity").InnerText
                        };

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item Name: {0} costs {1} and we have a quantity of {2}", item.Name, item.Price, item.Quantity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Performance**

On the question of performance: only you can answer that, as it's very much dependent on what *you're* doing and how quickly *you* need it to do it. If you have a batch process that runs once a month and takes 30 minutes to run, you may well decide that's quick enough. If the code's clear, concise and maintainable then re-writing it so that ran in half the time but was much more convoluted wouldn't be doing you, or anyone else who has to maintain it in the future, any favours.

Comment: As a slight expansion of the above - the key is, a suggested, to use the newer XDocument, XElement, XAttribute etc classes and Linq to XML rather than the older and clunkier XmlXXX classes. Linq to XML is pretty nice for querying (and you can use XPath if you want) and its pretty close to essential for "document" creation.

Comment: NLV,... are you sure? WCF Service Applications weren't introduced until .net 3.0 . I've just verified this by attempting to create one in VS2k5 with the "New Project" windows Framework drop-down set to .NET Framework 2.0 and it wasn't listed as an option..

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm using VS 2005 and i've installed WCF template (Nov 2006 CTP). Okie, i'm working on 3.0. But VS2005 sucks with Linq syntaxing. BTW, how do you get the 'select framework' dropdown in VS 2005. I thought it is only available in VS 2008 and VS 2010. :)